# Decorator in class: cannot use self inside the decorated function

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to implement a custom logger with a decorator that would collect exceptions (to save them to db later) in the following way:

```
import functools

class Log:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mssg = ""
        self.err = ""

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Log()

    def logging(fun):
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def inner(*args):
            try:                
                print(fun.__name__)
                self.logger.mssg += fun.__name__ +" :ok, "  
                return fun(*args)

            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.err += fun.__name__ +": error: "+str(e.args) 
        return inner

    logging = staticmethod(logging)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b): 
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @Parent.logging
    def sum_(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

However it seems that the decorator "break" the link between the method and the instance, as it cannot use self anymore...  when running

```
c = Child(3,6)
c.sum_()
```

I receive an error message `self is not defined` I also tried various combination to pass `self.logger`as an argument to the function, but I am a bit confused, and they failed... Anyone have an idea that could solve my problem?

Comment: At a guess, `self` in the logging method is not defined, since it's not explicitly passed as an argument to either `logging` or `inner`. You likely need to grab it from (the first element of) `*args`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with your code. Look at the comments.

```
import functools

class Log:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mssg = ""
        self.err = ""

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Log()

    @staticmethod   #You can directly use staticmethod decorator!
    def logging(fun):
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def inner(*args):
            self = args[0]  #Grab the first arg as self.
            try:                
                print(fun.__name__)
                self.logger.mssg += fun.__name__ +" :ok, "  
                return fun(self, *(args[1:]))  # Call the function using
                                               # self that we extracted.
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.err += fun.__name__ +": error: "+str(e.args) 
        return inner

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Child, self).__init__()   #Don't forget call the parent ctor
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @Parent.logging
    def sum_(self):
        return self.a + self.b

c = Child(3,6)
print c.sum_()  #Outputs 9
```

Comment: You could also define `inner` as `def inner(self, *args)` so you not only get the `self` for free but you directly see that the decorstor creates a method.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Thax this is awesome! 1 thing I dont understand is the line `super(Child, self).__init__()` . What is this doing?

Comment: @SuperSaiyan actually now i understand, but why is it better than calling Parent.__init__()

Answer (score 0):

As you may have done it intentionally, making a function in a class a `staticmethod` makes it "static", making it not able to access the "self" attribute of the instance. Plus, the `__init__` of the class never ran because you never created an instance of the class.

You can alternatively do something like this by creating a Parent instance in the Child namescope:

Note: This method does not involve inheritance, if you believe it is a necessity, try @SuperSaiyan 's answer

```
import functools

class Log:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mssg = ""
        self.err = ""

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Log()

    def logging(self, fun): # include the "self" argument as it is no longer static
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def inner(*args):
            try:
                print(fun.__name__)
                self.logger.mssg += fun.__name__ +" :ok, "
                return fun(*args)

            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.err += fun.__name__ +": error: "+str(e.args)
        return inner

class Child: # you do not need to inherit the Parent class if it's only used for the decorator

    myparent = Parent() # initiates the logger and create an instance of that class
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @myparent.logging # use myparent instead of Parent
    def sum_(self):
        return self.a + self.b

c = Child(3, 6)
print(c.sum_()) # prints sum_ and 9
```

Comment: @abccd I am using inheritance as in my real life code I want to appply the logger to different classes... without having to copy paste it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as shown in the following code, which variess from your approach in two primary ways. It changes `logging` into a (nested) class and implements it as a singleton so only one instance of it will ever be created.

Doing this means you must invoke the decorator with `@Parent.logging()` instead of just `@Parent.logging`. This ensures there's that a `Log` instance is created and assigned to `self.logger` where `self` is that the `logging` class's singleton instance. Note that `__call__()` is **not** a staticmethod.

```
import functools

class Log(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = ""
        self.err = ""

class Parent(object):
    class logging(object):  # singleton decorator class
        def __init__(self):
            self.logger = Log()

        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            if '_inst_' not in vars(cls):
                cls._inst = object.__new__(cls)
            return cls._inst

        def __call__(self, fun):
            @functools.wraps(fun)
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    print(fun.__name__)
                    self.logger.msg += fun.__name__+" :ok, "
                    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as exc:
                    self.logger.err += fun.__name__+": error: "+str(exc.args)
            return inner

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Child, self).__init__()   # initialize Parent
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @Parent.logging()  # must call and create decorator instance
    def sum_(self):
        return self.a + self.b

c = Child(3, 6)
print(c.sum_())  # -> 9
```